# I accidentally marked the wrong question as a duplicate. How can I replace it with the correct duplicate?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I accidentally flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929038/is-there-a-way-to-print-ruby-function-source-like-javascripts-functiontostrin) as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function), when I intended to flag it as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-methods-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-m). I am presented with the message "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention" whenever I try to replace the incorrect duplicate flag. Is there any way that I can fix this mistake, even though Stack Overflow is preventing me from fixing it?

Comment: Self Flagellation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagellation

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards The other question doesn't discuss the problem of adding an additional flag, and being prevented from adding that flag. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: same difference. You can't retract a flag. Since you can't flag a post twice before the first flag is handled, you're stuck.

Comment: Mat has essentially written what I would have; I've read your question a couple of times not and there _may_ be a different question in there if you want there to be, if you're asking _"I recognise that I can't tell the system that I've made a mistake but how can I tell other users"_ My answer to that would be to comment, which isn't that much of a revelation...

Answer (score 2):

Post a comment with a link to the real duplicate.  The flag will (hopefully) be declined, but someone else should be able to come along and use the link you provide to close it against the appropriate question.

Comment: Hopefully the ability to undo flags will be implemented in Stack Overflow one day. It's irritating when I make an incorrect flag and then have no way to replace it with the correct one.